# unable to a decode_json in php

Tags: php, json

I have A Json data  But I am unable to get desired response.

```
$content='{"success":true,"results":[{"id":"21390fb46e92","msisdncountrycode":"DE","msisdn":"+491788735000","statuscode":"HLRSTATUS_UNDELIVERED","hlrerrorcodeid":9,"subscriberstatus":"SUBSCRIBERSTATUS_ABSENT","imsi":null,"mccmnc":"26203","mcc":"262","mnc":"03","msin":null,"servingmsc":null,"servinghlr":null,"originalnetworkname":"E-Plus","originalcountryname":"Germany","originalcountrycode":"DE","originalcountryprefix":"+49","originalnetworkprefix":"178","roamingnetworkname":null,"roamingcountryname":null,"roamingcountrycode":null,"roamingcountryprefix":null,"roamingnetworkprefix":null,"portednetworkname":null,"portedcountryname":null,"portedcountrycode":null,"portedcountryprefix":null,"portednetworkprefix":null,"isvalid":"Yes","isroaming":"No","isported":"No","usercharge":"0.0100","inserttime":"2015-11-24 18:56:42.048693+08","storage":"CURL-TEST","route":"IP1"}]}';
```

i want to capture some contents like

id , msisdncountrycode , msisdncountrycode , statuscode , hlrerrorcodeid

And Other Values As Well Please Help To Solve This problem .

Comment: json_decode($content, true);

Comment: please elaborate with complete example in php code , i am new in php

Answer (score 1):

check out this:

```
$result = json_decode($content);
var_dump($result->results[0]->id);//will get id
var_dump($result->results[0]->msisdncountrycode);//will get Country code
```

Answer (score 1):

use this(works with multiple results).

```
$d = json_decode($content);

foreach($d->results as $row){
    echo $row->id; //echoes 21390fb46e92
    echo $row->msisdncountrycode; //echoes DE
    echo $row->statuscode; //echoes HLRSTATUS_UNDELIVERED
    echo $row->hlrerrorcodeid; //echoes 9
}
```

Echoes are based on current input. Since its in loop, it will print all values.

Comment: Nice, I didn't seen multiple objects in array..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Its working fine for me.

```
json_decode($content)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$content='{"success":true,"results":[{"id":"21390fb46e92","msisdncountrycode":"DE","msisdn":"+491788735000","statuscode":"HLRSTATUS_UNDELIVERED","hlrerrorcodeid":9,"subscriberstatus":"SUBSCRIBERSTATUS_ABSENT","imsi":null,"mccmnc":"26203","mcc":"262","mnc":"03","msin":null,"servingmsc":null,"servinghlr":null,"originalnetworkname":"E-Plus","originalcountryname":"Germany","originalcountrycode":"DE","originalcountryprefix":"+49","originalnetworkprefix":"178","roamingnetworkname":null,"roamingcountryname":null,"roamingcountrycode":null,"roamingcountryprefix":null,"roamingnetworkprefix":null,"portednetworkname":null,"portedcountryname":null,"portedcountrycode":null,"portedcountryprefix":null,"portednetworkprefix":null,"isvalid":"Yes","isroaming":"No","isported":"No","usercharge":"0.0100","inserttime":"2015-11-24 18:56:42.048693+08","storage":"CURL-TEST","route":"IP1"}]}';
echo '<pre>';
$jsonArr = json_decode($content, TRUE);
$outputArr = $jsonArr['results'][0];
print_r($outputArr);
$id = $outputArr['id'];
$msisdncountrycode = $outputArr['msisdncountrycode'];
$statuscode = $outputArr['statuscode'];
$hlrerrorcodeid = $outputArr['hlrerrorcodeid'];
?>
```